# Defining Laravel Relationship in Custom Primary Key and Foreign Key

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have 2 tables and It is One to One Relationship Model Type.

Students Table = id|nik|name|address. Accounts Table = id|nik|username|password.

In this case every student has one account and i took NIK as the $primaryKey in student model. How to define a relationship for that? Thanks in advance.

```
// Student Model
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class, 'nik', 'nik');
}

// Account Model
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'nik', 'nik');
}
```

Comment: what is not working here??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon It produce an error "Trying to get property 'account' of non-object" when I try to get the relationship data $student->account;

Comment: if the error is `Trying to get property 'account' of non-object` then its your student is undefined. not the relationship.. how are you retrieving the student?

Answer (score 0):

In your students table, you should define a new column with name 'account_id' to represent the student account, and it should be nullable.

```
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('account_id')->nullable();
  $table->foreign('account_id')->references('nik')->on('accounts');
```

then , you can use it in your relation:

```
// Student Model
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class, 'account_id', 'nik');
}

// Account Model
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'account_id', 'nik');
}
```

Comment: // Student Model
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class, 'student_id', 'nik');
}

Comment: it depends on the app requirements, can an account exist without a student?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have one field (nik) repeated in two tables that's against database normalization. You should create student_id on Account table. That way you would be following Laravel's standard on One to One relationships.

```
// Student Model
public function account()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Account::class);
}

// Account Model
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```